# Custom appendix in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm Trying to solve a little problem that I have with a book I'm writing, I was wondering if could you give me a hand with my work.

I'm trying to rename the automatic captions in the appendix's tables
that I have. By default Latex do this:

Appendix A:

Table A.1
Table A.2
.
.

Appendix B:

Table B.1
Table B.2
.
.

The problem is: I have 6 chapters in my book, but each chapter except
the first one have appendices and All appendix go in the end of the
book. And All tables and figures in the appendix are A not B or C,
like this:

Anexo 2   <- The renamed appendix 2

Table A2_1
Table A2_2
Table A2_3
.
.

Anexo 3

Table A3_1
Table A3_2
Table A3_3
.
.

Could you help me??? I'll appreciate it so much

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, to change 'appendix' to 'Anexo',

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
```

The \appendix command changes the way sectional units are numbered. I too have found the \appendix command sometimes causes problems since everything which follows it is treated as part of the appendix.

You can create a section labelled 'Appendix' with distinctive numbering by using the \section command with suitably redefined commands for the counters. The following example generates a single 'Appendix' with equations numbered A-1, A-2, ...

```
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{A-\arabic{equation}}    
  % redefine the command that creates the equation no.    
  \setcounter{equation}{0}  % reset counter     
  \section*{APPENDIX}  % use *-form to suppress numbering
```

With several appendices you can get appropriate numbering by redefining the \thesection command and resetting the section counter.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the `appendix` package and its `appendices` environment. For localized names, look into the `babel` package instead.